# How can I get images drawn with drawImage to be included when using toDataURL?

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas

I'm working on a page where you will be able to draw images on a canvas. You have 6 options of images, and when you are done I want people to able to save their creation.

I'm using `drawImage` to draw the images on the canvas, but when I use the following code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

It doesn't show the drawn images on the `DataUrl` images.

How can I make sure that the images that are drawn on the canvas are also visible in the image given by `toDataURL`?

Comment: It should work unless your browser does not support displaying data urls. in that case you need to to process the result serverside and serve the resulting png.

Comment: it works, normal lines that i draw on it i see on the dtaturl, but drawimages that i draw on the canvas are not shown. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the URLs of your page and the images you are drawing?

If your images are not coming from the same origin as the page, you will not be able to use `toDataURL` or any other methods to read the contents of the canvas; this is an intentional security feature.  Check your JavaScript error console and you may see something like "DOM ERROR" or "SECURITY EXCEPTION".

**What** do I mean?  I mean that if your page is at some URL (e.g., `test.com`, `localhost:8080`, `file:///home/foo/`) and the images you are drawing are located at URLs with different origins (`google.com` is a different origin from `test.com`, `localhost:3000` is a different origin from `localhost:8080`, some browsers treat `file:///` urls as if they are always from a different origin) then the browser will mark your canvas as unreadable once you draw the image to it.

**Why** is it this way?  Pages can display images from other origins, but many other forms of cross-origin access are denied unless explicitly granted-- `XMLHttpRequest`s, for example.

`file` URLs are treated differently as well because they are potentially more abusable.  If you are using local files for the page and images, serve them with a trivial web server instead.

[The first bullet in this section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements) applies.

Comment: What are the URLs of the page and your images?  `file://`?

Comment: im just doing it local, so i got some images on my computer and the html page with the code is in the same place on my pc. but i thought i worked on IE but it doesnt

Comment: it works to save the added images on the canvas, but at the begin i ad a picture as background, somehow it doesnt save that images but al the other later added images are working :)